# Add column to plugins table screen

Tags: plugins, screen-columns

I'm trying to add a column to plugin table screen using "manage_plugins_custom_column", but without success.

This extra column will show a custom value that was placed inside the plugin file.

I hope someone could help!

Thanks!
Daniel

---------------- edit ----------------

This is the working code that creates the column "Version":

```
function add_plugins_column( $columns ) {
$columns = array(
"name" => __( 'Plugin', '' ),
"version" => __( 'Version', '' ),
"description" => __( 'Description', '' ),
);
return $columns;
} add_filter( 'manage_plugins_columns', 'add_plugins_column' );

function render_plugins_column( $column, $plugin_file, $plugin_data ) {
switch ($column) {
case "version": echo $plugin_data['Version']; break;
}
} add_action( 'manage_plugins_custom_column' , 'render_plugins_column', 10, 3 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to add the custom column to the plugin column names:

```
function wpa65189_add_plugins_column( $columns ) {
    $columns['wpa65189_column'] = 'wpa65189 Custom Column';
    return $columns;
}
add_filter( 'manage_plugins_columns', 'wpa65189_add_plugins_column' );
```

Then output your column data for your plugin:

```
function wpa65189_render_plugins_column( $column_name, $plugin_file, $plugin_data ) {
    if ( 'wpa65189_column' == $column_name && 'My Plugin Name' == $plugin_data['Name'] ) :
        echo 'My Plugin custom column data';
    endif;
}
add_action( 'manage_plugins_custom_column' , 'wpa65189_render_plugins_column', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Thanks Milo! Your code works great! Just one more question: How can I show a plugin header information like version in this column?

Comment: `$plugin_data` array contains all the header info, for version `echo $plugin_data['Version']`

Comment: I already tried this, but doesn't work for me. My function looks like this: function render_plugins_column( $column ) {

switch ($column) {
case "version": echo $plugin_data['Version']; break;
}} add_action( 'manage_plugins_custom_column' , 'render_plugins_column', 10, 3 );

Comment: $column will contain the name of any custom columns, your function doesn't work because there is no column named 'version' unless you add one.

Comment: Sure. This is the second function (render_plugins_column). The first function (add_plugins_column) creates the column "version". I'll post a answer with the actual code.

Comment: your `render_plugins_column` function is missing the 2nd and 3rd arguments: `render_plugins_column( $column, $plugin_file, $plugin_data )`

Comment: Milo, do you know how can I print a variable located in the plugin file in this new column?